# Wordpress Storefront Header added text. Hide on mobile?

Tags: wordpress, storefront

So I managed to add a text and link in theme Storefronts header. And place it quite ok. See code from function.php below. How can I hide this on a mobile? I am familiar with how to use style.css for customizing, but not with this. I tried to add `<div class="hide-on-mobile">` before the div style but nothing changed. Thanks!

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'pfn_mypage', 44 );
function pfn_mypage() { ?>
<div style="text-align: right; float: right; margin-left: 1%;">
    <a href="\my-account">My Page</a></div>
   <?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. This was embarrasing. I did this `<div class="lhut"><a href="\my-account">My Page</a></div>` 
and it worked.

Thank you!